# Can override __get from outside of a class

Tags: php

I have a class which contains a `__get`er which will return a computed value.

The `__get`er in my class could look like this:

```
public function __get($name) {
    switch ($name) {
        case "OnePlusOne":
            return (1 + 1);
            break;

        default:
            return null;
            break;
    }
}
```

Then I use my class:

```
$aclass = new MyClass();
$aclass->OnePlusOne = 5;
echo ($aclass->OnePlusOne); /* returns 5 instead of 2 */
```

How to make sure that it is **not** possible to change my class in this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `__set()` method that prevents any property you have defined as computed from being set.

```
public function __set($name, $value)
{
    $computedProperties = ["OnePlusOne"];
    if (!in_array($name, $computedProperties)) {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: But then I can still add new properties to that class, right? Maybe by accident (wrong typo)

Comment: Oh, do you want to prevent adding any new properties at all? I thought you just wanted to prevent adding new properties that would overwrite the computed ones.

Comment: Yes, exactly, no new properties at all

Comment: In that case, just don't do anything in `__set()`. If you really need to prevent setting any properties dynamically I'd suggest throwing an exception in `__set()` to clearly set that expectation rather than just allowing it to silently fail to do anything.